# How to format a floating number to fixed width with forced sign in Python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a number to fixed width with a sign in Python - I can do one or the other but not both:`'{:>5+.0f}'.format(43.5)`
doesn't work (ValueError: Invalid conversion specification)

My current workaround is to do: `'{:>5}'.format('{:+.0f}'.format(43.5))`

But it doesn't seem very pretty - is there a way to do it all in one string format?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the + and 5. (Thanks @Alik for pointing out the space is not needed)

```
>>> '{:>+5.0f}'.format(43.5)
'  +44'
```

or even remove the `>` altogether.

```
>>> '{:+5.0f}'.format(47.55)
'  +44'
```

Comment: (you beat me in 2 seconds, I was about to answer the same answer)

Comment: Relevant documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language